# Retorno Json PHP para Ajax em branco

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm learning PHP and JS, and while doing a Get with Ajax, the PH return is coming in white. I'm turning the net but not finding anything, I'd like some help.

```
  $idEvent = $_REQUEST["idEvent"];
  $event = $this->model->getById($idEvent);
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($event, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  exit;
```

```
$('#ShowEvent').click(function() {

        var idEvent = document.getElementById("ShowEvent").getAttribute("idEvent");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/salgadar/public_html/Event/GetEventById',
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                idEvent: idEvent
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('AJAX call was successful!');
                $("#AjaxReturn").html(data)
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('There was some error performing the AJAX call!');
            }
        });

        console.log(data);
    });
```

ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Please note that you have to ask in English on this site - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange (or use one of the language-specific versions of the site.) Someone has halfway fixed that for you by editing your question, but the title does still not match that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First place the console.log() inside your ajax call, like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/salgadar/public_html/Event/GetEventById',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            idEvent: idEvent
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            alert('AJAX call was successful!');

            console.log(data); //HERE CODE

            $("#AjaxReturn").html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('There was some error performing the AJAX call!');
        }
    });
```

Then tell me what appears and we will continue to solve the problems.

Comment: Return: ReferenceError: data is not defined